# Delete comments from CQ5 blog publish instance

Tags: aem

I am creating a blog page in CQ5.6 (AEM). Rest apart, once I publish the page and it is visible to public, how will I be able to delete/moderate derogatory comments, if needed ?

I do have the option on the author instance by right clicking and deleting the comment. But I am not sure how it works on the publish instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete (or deactivate) content on the author instance, this polls the attached publish instances to remove the content there. This helps too, if you have more than one publish instance attached to an authoring instance.

The [docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/social_communities/ModeratingSocialCommunitiesSites.html) mention the actions that you can take within the **comment moderation** workflow & how they'll affect the content on the publish instance:

> - **Approve Comment:**
>     The comment is displayed on both the authored and the published page.
> - **Delete Comment:**
>     The comment is removed from both the authored and the published page.
> - **Ignore Comment:**
>     The comment is displayed on the authored page and removed from the published page.

Answer (score 0):

Replication from author to publish will handle deleting the comment on the publish node.

1. user posts comment on publish node2
2. reverse replication brings comment to author instance
3. Author reviews comment on author instance
4. replication pushes result to all publish nodes (either add comment node to all, or writes empty node, which is effectively a delete node)